# same scale of Y axis on differents figures

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, figure

I try to plot different data with similar representations but slight different behaviours and different origins on several figures. So the min & max of the Y axis is different between each figure, but the scale too.

e.g. here are some extracts of my batch plotting :

[image]
[image]

Does it exists a simple way with matplotlib to constraint the same Y step on those different figures, in order to have an easy visual interpretation, while keeping an automatically determined Y min and Y max ?

In others words, I'd like to have the same *metric* spacing between each Y-tick

Comment: Be more specific. Show us some data, what you've tried, what it produces, and how you'd like it to be different.

Comment: Do you mean the same data coordinate difference between where ticks are located, as shown in @tom's answer, or the same axes coordinate difference (meaning that `ymax - ymin` is the same for all plots of the same size)?

Comment: @askewchan the second option :that Ymax - Ymin is the same for every plot. For the moment, the only way I found is 1) calc Ymax - Ymin for each dataset and find the biggest range 2) calc the medium value for each dataset 3) eventually, setting the Ymin and Ymax with Ymean ± Yrange/2... And with a second dataset it's going worse... I'm searching for a function to easily set the value of the Yrange (estimated grossly and manually before)

Comment: That's pretty much what I would do, @Covich. You can get `yrange` from the plots though, not the data, if you wish: `ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a [`MultipleLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator) from the [`ticker`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) module on both axes to define the tick spacings:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(212)
ax1.set_ylim(0,100)
ax2.set_ylim(40,70)

# set ticks every 10
tickspacing = 10
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(base=tickspacing)) 
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(base=tickspacing))

plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

It seems like your desired behaviour was different to how I interpreted your question. Here is a function that will change the limits of the y axes to make sure `ymax-ymin` is the same for both subplots, using the larger of the two `ylim` ranges to change the smaller one.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(212)
ax1.set_ylim(40,50)
ax2.set_ylim(40,70)

def adjust_axes_limits(ax1,ax2):

    yrange1 = np.ptp(ax1.get_ylim())
    yrange2 = np.ptp(ax2.get_ylim())

    def change_limits(ax,yr):
        new_ymin = ax.get_ylim()[0] - yr/2.
        new_ymax = ax.get_ylim()[1] + yr/2.
        ax.set_ylim(new_ymin,new_ymax)

    if yrange1 > yrange2:
        change_limits(ax2,yrange1-yrange2)
    elif yrange2 > yrange1:
        change_limits(ax1,yrange2-yrange1)
    else:
        pass

adjust_axes_limits(ax1,ax2)
plt.show()
```

Note that the first subplot here has expanded from `(40, 50)` to `(30, 60)`, to match the y range of the second subplot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Tom is pretty fine !
But I decided to use a simpler solution

I define an arbitrary `yrange` for all my plots e.g.

```
yrang = 0.003
```

and for each plot, I do :

```
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
ymid = np.mean([ymin,ymax])
ax.set_ylim([ymid - yrang/2 , ymid + yrang/2])
```

and possibly:

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(base=0.005))
```